# R-PropTest in Java

Tags: java, r, statistics, chi-squared

I have a 2X2 Matrix and am doing prop_test in R and then take the P value from the result.

Now, I want to do the same thing in Java i.e., computing the P value.

One way is to use https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/inference/ChiSquareTest.html and compute the P-value

But, chi-square test does not use a Yates' continuity correction which can result in differences between R's approach and ChiSquareTest approach.

I would like to know any other ways to get the P-Value using Yates' continuity correction

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yates%27s_correction_for_continuity It's not that bad to calculate the Chi-square statistic by hand. Then use the apache library to calculate the p-value based off of that.